# Inserting a new text at given cursor position

Tags: codemirror

I am working on customizing the codemirror for my new language mode. As part of this new mode implementation, I am writing a new tool bar where user can select some text and say insert. This command should insert the text where user was typing just before clicking on tool bar.

I could not find any API level support to do so. If there is any other way can someone help me out on this?

Basically get the current cursor positio- line number and position at which cursor is currently present. May be a Position object

API for inserting a text, something like `insertText("Text", PositionObject)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about `replaceSelection` (http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#replaceSelection)?

> **doc.replaceSelection(replacement: string, ?select: string)**
>   Replace the selection(s) with the given string. By default, the new selection ends up after the inserted text. The optional select argument can be used to change this—passing "around" will cause the new text to be selected, passing "start" will collapse the selection to the start of the inserted text.

Comment: Does this work properly in IE9? I am using it IE9 but once the text is inserted, I am not able to add any chars further. Is this something u noticed it when you developing the code mirror?

Answer (score 24):

Here's how I did it:

```
function insertTextAtCursor(editor, text) {
    var doc = editor.getDoc();
    var cursor = doc.getCursor();
    doc.replaceRange(text, cursor);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

**To add the new line at the end -**

```
function updateCodeMirror(data){
    var cm = $('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror;
    var doc = cm.getDoc();
    var cursor = doc.getCursor(); // gets the line number in the cursor position
    var line = doc.getLine(cursor.line); // get the line contents
    var pos = { // create a new object to avoid mutation of the original selection
        line: cursor.line,
        ch: line.length - 1 // set the character position to the end of the line
    }
    doc.replaceRange('\n'+data+'\n', pos); // adds a new line
}
```

Call function

```
updateCodeMirror("This is new line");
```

Comment: How to get the CodeMirror cm instance from @ctrl/ngx-codemirror library. No documentation exists in the git

Answer (score 9):

**Improved function that, if selection present, replaces the text, if not, inserts in current cursor position**

```
function insertString(editor,str){

        var selection = editor.getSelection();

        if(selection.length>0){
            editor.replaceSelection(str);
        }
        else{

            var doc = editor.getDoc();
            var cursor = doc.getCursor();

            var pos = {
               line: cursor.line,
               ch: cursor.ch
            }

            doc.replaceRange(str, pos);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Please don't add an extra answer when you improve your existing one. Edit the first one instead

Comment: Best solution, handles replacing selected text.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the [replaceRange](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#replaceRange) function. Even though the name says "replace", it also serves as "insert" depending on the arguments. From the documentation at the time I write this:

> Replace the part of the document between from and to with the given
>   string. from and to must be {line, ch} objects. to can be left off to
>   simply insert the string at position from. When origin is given, it
>   will be passed on to "change" events, and its first letter will be
>   used to determine whether this change can be merged with previous
>   history events, in the way described for selection origins.

Answer (score 3):

Final function to insert text at current cursor position in a performant way.
Hope it helps.

```
function insertStringInTemplate(str)
{
    var doc = editor_template.getDoc();
    var cursor = doc.getCursor();

    var pos = {
        line: cursor.line,
        ch: cursor.ch
    }

    doc.replaceRange(str, pos);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Works very well, had problems using setCursor method

Answer (score 0):

This function is used to insert to the specified position and move the cursor to the end of the inserted text.

```
  function insertToCodeMirror(text) {
    const doc = codeMirrorInstance.getDoc();
    const cursor = codeMirrorInstance.getCursor();
    doc.replaceRange(text, cursor);
    codeMirrorInstance.focus();
    setTimeout(() => {
      cursor.ch += text.length;
      codeMirrorInstance.setCursor(cursor);
    }, 0);
  }
```