# Deleteing character at a position, Codemirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I have to delete a character at a particular position from Codemirror Textarea. In order to insert characters at a position, I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733455/inserting-a-new-text-at-given-cursor-position) but no luck for deleting character. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use plain vanilla JS?

Comment: may i know how can it solve my problem ?p.s. I have never used JS library.

Comment: You could use the JS `string.replace()` method. Learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: sir, what if the string is "this is a my codemirrora" and we use replace(), in order to replace 'a' which is at the last, this method will result in inconsistent string.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass the [`replaceRange`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#replaceRange) method the position before the character as second, and the position after it as third argument, the given content (first argument, which can be `""`) will replace that character.