# CodeMirror - Inserting Code Via JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

Ok, so a bit of an odd question, but I've been trying for ages and cant get it to work.

So I have my text area

```
<textarea class="code" id="lecode" name="lecode">
</textarea>
```

And I've got all the files required for CodeMirror

And the code to start CM is like so

```
function createEditor() {
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("lecode"), {
        lineNumbers: true,
        mode: "text/html",
        indentUnit: 4,
        indentWithTabs: true
    });
}
createEditor()
```

I then have this code that types out a predefined variable into CM, but it wont work

```
jQuery.fn.simulateKeyPress = function(character) {
    jQuery(this).trigger({
        type: 'keypress',
        which: character.charCodeAt(0)
    });
};

var showText = function(target, message, index, interval) {
    if (index < message.length) {
        $(target).append(message[index++]); //Adds It To The Original TextArea
        $('.CodeMirror div:first textarea').simulateKeyPress(message[index++]); //Adds It To What I Think Is The Input TextArea For CM
        $('#lecode').scrollTop($('#lecode')[0].scrollHeight);
        setTimeout(function() {
            showText(target, message, index, interval);
        }, interval);
    }
}

showText("#lecode", linesfinal, 0, 1);
```

So my question is, how can I get this to work? The aim is to take a predefined variable (with code in it) and then type it out character by character into CM, so it is syntax-highlighted.

Please do ask if you need more of an explanation, but tell me what needs explaining, I'm useless at explaining and asking questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use the code mirror methods and not on the textarea. This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733455/inserting-a-new-text-at-given-cursor-position

Comment: Thanks! That was just what I needed!